# BIP44 Account Discovery using Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core, bip44

I have an address I suspect that I generated after I made a backup of `wallet.dat`, and I read about account discovery in BIP44. Does Bitcoin Core support this, and if so, how can I initiate it?

I’d like to restore the address to the wallet.

The wallet file is from 2019, and the current Bitcoin Core version I'm using is `0.21.0`.

`getwalletinfo` output:

```
{
    "result": {
        "walletname": "main",
        "walletversion": 169900,
        "format": "bdb",
        "balance": xxx,
        "unconfirmed_balance": 0,
        "immature_balance": 0,
        "txcount": 4,
        "keypoololdest": 1615166340,
        "keypoolsize": 1000,
        "hdseedid": "<seed_id>",
        "keypoolsize_hd_internal": 1000,
        "paytxfee": 0,
        "private_keys_enabled": true,
        "avoid_reuse": false,
        "scanning": false,
        "descriptors": false
    },
    "error": null,
    "id": <id>
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how the two parts of your question are related. What do you want to do with this address? What does it have to do with BIP44?

Comment: I’d like to find an address that is being used (has unspent outputs), but that the current wallet hasn’t derived yet. (Because it was derived after the wallet was backed up and then subsequently restored).

Comment: Well Bitcoin Core doesn't use BIP44 for deriving addresses, so that's not where you'd look. Normally you shouldn't need to do anything - Bitcoin Core contains a pool of future addresses to use (typically 1000 of them), which is included in the backup, so restoring the backup should give you access to all of those automatically, and it should show up in the balance. If not we'd probably need a bit more information, like which version are you using, how old is the wallet file; can you include the output of `getwalletinfo`?

Comment: What does `getaddressinfo <that address>` say?